# Override default sound when keys pressed on keyboard

Tags: android, audio, keyboard, keypress

I got a strange request from the client that I can't convince him to drop.  He wants that everywhere a soft keyboard is used, every time a key is pressed, a specific sound is played *instead* of the default keyboard sound.  In addition, he wants a tactile feedback on every keyboard press - regardless of whether this is turned on or off in the keyboard settings..  Furthermore, this needs to happen regardless of which keyboard is being used - stock or custom.

I now how to play a sound and vibrate when a key is pressed on the soft keyboard - however this would end up being *in addition* to the default settings on the keyboard.  Is there any way to override the default settings of the keyboard only in my app?

Comment: Possible solution to the first issue is to disable default button click sound in styles.xml file by adding android:soundEffectsEnabled="false".

Comment: @floyd this doesn't work, as this only applies to the view itself.  In case of a keyboard, the sound effects are those for clicking keyboard buttons - and I obviously don't control those views